# Bosonization of critical theories without $U(1)$ symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, ising-model, spin-chains, bosonization

When studying lattice models using bosonization, we expect the total charge is conserved so that the elementary excitation is particle-hole-like bosonic degrees of freedom. How about models without $U(1)$ symmetry? For example, the quantum Ising chain with only $Z_2$ symmetry? Can one still use bosonic fields to study its low-energy physics (near the critical point)?

Comment: The massive Schwinger model with theta angle $\theta = \pi$ has a "hidden" $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry which can be easily seen after bosonizing it into a massive sine-Gordon model with an explicit $\phi \rightarrow -\phi$ symmetry. This model has a phase transition in the Ising universality class, see the early sections of https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.72.224414 for more details.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt  Thanks for the reference. Any idea for the original models with only $Z_2$ symmetry? A lattice model for example. Your example is more like there is $U(1)$ in the theory, but some relevant operators break it.

Comment: I thought the Ising model was the bosonized version of the free Majorana fermion.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Sorry, I mean using the bosonic field to study the fermionic version of the Ising model. So first Majorana fermion version of Ising model and then bosonization. In practice, one can directly write down the bosonization dictionary between spin operator and bosonic field, right?